# Errors-in-variables random effects meta-regression

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression, network-meta-analysis, meta-learning, reliability-meta-analysis

I would like to perform an error-in-variables random effects (DerSimonian and Laird method) meta-regression, but I do not know how one goes about doing this. Does anyone have any advice on if this is possible in SPSS or Stata?

To put the relevant data simply: I have a dependent variable composed of effect sizes and associated SEs and an independent variable composed of reporting odds ratios and associated SEs.